# How to generate alerts for Azure Tags

Tags: azure, automation, monitoring

Is there a way to create an alert from azure portal via log analytics query, when a Virtual Machine doesn't have any tags or minimum tags than needed

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce tags on resources using [Azure Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-value):

How-to: https://blogs.endjin.com/2019/04/enforce-resource-tagging-with-azure-policy/

You can start by creating Audit-policies with will create events in the activity log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#audit

Later then you can also create deny-policies to enforce tags on resource creation.

Answer (score 0):

We use Azure Policy to do it. Here a blog post how to do it https://blogs.endjin.com/2019/04/enforce-resource-tagging-with-azure-policy/